# gnu make executes rule even if target is not updated

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have builder.sh file. It can (optionally) update file effect.cpp. If the was updated it should be copyed to src dir.

builder.sh should be executed every time (create rule) and effect.cpp should be copyed only if it is updated (move rule).

I have created makefile:

```
gen: create move

create:
    cd generated && ./builder.sh build

move: generated/effect.cpp
    cp generated/effect.cpp src/effect.cpp
```

But it copy effect.cpp even if it was not updated. How it can be fixed?

Comment: How are you calling Make? The default target updates the generated file first, so `move` would then copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it copy effect.cpp even if it was not updated.

Well yes. `make` has no idea about whether `generated/effect.cpp` has been updated.  It can determine only whether it is newer than another file, and the other file it will consider is the target of the rule, "move".  And since there is no such file, and the `move` rule does not, in fact, create it, the recipe for its rule will be run every time `make` determines that `move` needs to be up to date.

Since the rule in question is for updating `src/effect.cpp`, that should be its target.  Additionally, `generated/effect.cpp` should be the target of the rule that creates *it*, which will also take care of the requirement that `builder.sh` be run first.  Making it depend on a non-existent target itself will ensure that its recipe is always run:

```
gen: src/effect.cpp

src/effect.cpp: generated/effect.cpp
    cp $< $@

generated/effect.cpp: FORCE
    cd generated && ./builder.sh build

FORCE:
```

Note that the name `FORCE` is just a convention.  It has no inherent significance to `make`.